# Get item from list

Tags: c#, list

I need to get an item from this list:

```
 {
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
        Location location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Location>(json);
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
        locations.Add(location);
        gvLocation.DataSource = locations;
        gvLocation.DataBind();
    }
```

I tried:

```
 var lat = Location[5];
```

but does not compile, "there is no variable or member 'location'.

I can I get the values out of the list?

Comment: Change `Location[5];` to `locations[5];`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Then change `location[5]` to `locations[5]`.

Comment: I tried it with "locations". Does not work, same error

Comment: Then you're doing it in a place where `locations` doesn't exist. Probably outside of that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name of your list is `locations` not `location`. And you are defining it inside of your method that means you cannot access it from outside.If you want to access your list from outside of the method, declare it in class level and initialize it inside:

```
List<Location> locations;
public void SomeMethod()
{
    locations = new List<Location>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var lat = locations[5];
```

You tried to access the Data type of the list members *Location* instead of the instance of the list *locations*.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a list's member by it's index.

```
var someLocation = locations[0];
```

The above gives the first element of the list `locations`

Also, the list has to have some 6 elements, before you call `locations[5];`

Otherwise, you'll get `IndexOutOfBoundException`